Confusion on Stability of Difference Equation Approximation to a simple, linear PDE initial value problem
We have a simple linear partial differential equation of the following form.
\begin{equation}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+ c \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0 \Bigg| (x, t) \in \mathbb R \times (\mathbb R^+ \cup \{0\}) \end{equation}
We also have the following initial value.
$$u(x, 0) = f(x)$$
We replace this with the following difference equation.
\begin{equation}\frac{v(x, t+k) - v(x, t)}{k}+ c \frac{v(x, t) - v(x-h, t)}{h} = 0\end{equation}
I introduce a general shift operator $E$ such that $E f(x) := f(x+h)$.
Re-arranging for $v(x, t+k)$ and letting $\lambda = \frac k h$, the following equation is obtained.
$$v(x, t + k) = ((1-\lambda c) + \lambda c E^{-1}) v(x, t)$$
Finally, if I let $t = nk$, I can get a sum that should converge to $u(x, t)$ when $h, k \to (0, 0)$ given $f$ has uniformly bounded second derivatives.
$$v(x, t) = \sum^n_{r=0} \binom{n}{r} (1-\lambda c)^r (\lambda c)^{n-r} f(x - (n-r)h)$$
By the method of characteristics, $u(x, t) = f(x-ct)$.
If I further use the condition that $\lambda c \leq 1$, I am supposed to be able to show the following inequality.
$$|u(x, t+k) - (1-\lambda c) u(x, t) - \lambda c u(x-h, t)|$$
$$= |f(x-ct-ck)-(1-\lambda c) f(x-ct) - \lambda c f(x-h-ct)| \leq \frac{1}{2}(c^2\lambda^2 + \lambda c) \sup|f''|$$
I don't exactly understand how this last statement comes about. This is from the first chapter of Fritz John's Applied Mathematical Sciences book from Springer Education on Partial Differential Equations. Any help would be appreciated.

I assume here that $k$ and $h$ are small, did you try to Taylor-expand the terms with $f$ around $k$ and $h$?

Yes, h and k need to be small for the PDE to realistically converge. But we let the choice of h and k be solely restricted by $\lambda c \leq 1$ depending on the PDE given. For now, this was just supposed to be a proof of stability and convergence of this numerical method. I understand the proof after the last statement is made but this last line is where I'm essentially stuck. I don't see how it holds true.

To be sure, your question is `how do I prove the inequality?'

Pretty much, yeah... I don't have any confusion with the rest of it.

We expand the three terms in the last line around the small parameters $h$ and $k$:
\begin{align*}
f(x-ct-ck)&=f(x-ct)-ckf'(x-ct)+\frac{1}{2}c^2k^2f''(x-ct)+\mathcal{O}(h^3)\\
-(1-\lambda c)f(x-ct)&=-(1-\lambda c)f(x-ct)\\
-\lambda cf(x-h-ct)&=-\lambda cf(x-ct)+h\lambda cf'(x-ct)-\frac{1}{2}\lambda ch^2f''(x-ct)+\mathcal{O}(k^3)\\
\end{align*}
When we sum these 3 and use $h\lambda=k$, we see that all terms with $f$ and $f'$ cancel. Hence
\begin{align*}
|f(x-ct-ck)-(1-\lambda c)f(x-ct)-\lambda cf(x-h-ct)|&=|(\frac{1}{2}c^2k^2-\frac{1}{2}\lambda ch^2)f''(x-ct)+h.o.t|\\
&\leq \frac{h^2}{2}(c^2\lambda^2+\lambda c)\sup_\xi |f''(\xi)|+h.o.t. 
\end{align*}
Hence, in your equation, $h^2$ is missing.

Hey, thanks... I actually asked one of my friends and they told me what to do so this response is somewhat late but it's fine. The $h^2$ goes away bcz of the other inequality which we assume later into the chapter. Thank you so much still!
